# Bitcoin client warning

Tags: blockchain, client, bitcoin-core, error

I get this warning on my Bitcoin client:
"Warning: Displayed transactions may not be correct! You may need to upgrade, or other nodes may need to upgrade."
I am also downloading the blockchain and i am stuck at "18 weeks behind" for days now. Is everything alright?

Comment: You are probably using an old version. Is this a new install? If you are using bitcoin-qt make sure you have at least version 0.8.5.

Comment: Yes it is a new installation. The version is 0.8.5-beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should download the bootstrap.dat - this will take the time for the blockchains to catch up from days to two hours... google it.